# latex placing image - how can I put image wherever I want

Tags: floats

I am trying to insert an image in the middle of the page, but it is going to the top of the page. why the hell is it happening?

I tried this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=75.5mm]{myimage}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

I am looking for solution for 2 hours, not a single sign of success!

Comment: This really is NOT a duplicate of the question it is linked to. And good answers to this question aren't covered in the answers there. Influencing the position of a float isn't the same as ensuring an image is right where I want it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only purpose of the `figure` environment is to allow LaTeX to move the figure, and a `minipage` inside figure has no purpose at all unless you have footnotes, so you just need

```
%\begin{figure}
% \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=75.5mm]{myimage}
%  \end{minipage}
%\end{figure}
```

and the image will appear wherever you have `\includegraphics` in the source.

Note the rules for placing images are the same as the rules for placing `X` Normally if you enter `X` it comes where you put it, either part of the current line, or perhaps indented at start of a paragraph. If you do

```
\begin{figure}
X
\end{figure}
```

Then the `X` will float and be positioned by the page breaking routines. `\includegraphics` works in exactly the same way, or said more correctly, the float placement routines have no information about the content of the figure environment.

Answer (score 5):

Figure is an floating object and minipage is not, so by encapsulating a minipage in a figure object you make the minipage floating.

Another option is using the "H" position specifier; http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

That being said, I prefer to let LaTeX control the position of the image and use a reference to that figure in your text. Letting LaTeX control the position of all elements of your page is in my option a more robust and neat solution.

Comment: If you put a figure inside a minipage you will get a syntax error and the float will be discarded.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I updated my answer